# loop throught all members of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
{
"USA":[{"country":"Albuquerque (ABQ)"},
        {"country":"Allentown (ABE)"}
        ],
"Canada":{"country":"Calgary (YYC)"},
"Hawaii":{"country":"Honolulu International Apt (HNL)"}
}
```

This is my object I need to loop  it through so i can get all the values like this

**USA**

- Albuquerque (ABQ)
- Allentown (ABE)

**Canade**

- Calgary (YYC)

Answer (score 3):

For the solution you can check out this demo.

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/chokchai/u2dYr/)</kbd>

You can loop Object using `for(k in obj)`

```
for(k in obj){
    var value = obj[k];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a jsfiddle for you at http://jsfiddle.net/5eM4q/

The way you access the data using

```
    data[obj].country
```

is incorrect